# Time Series Classification Problem: Training EEG dataset with Sliding Window and Majority Vote

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm working to a classification problem (**Emotion Recognition throuhg EEG data**) with a custom dataset (not publically available, for now) in pytorch.
EEG data are samples of shape *(C, T)*, with *C* being the number of channels (electrodes) and *T* the number of time-points (variable-lenth samples, say *T* in range [9000-120000] time points). Each sample has a emotion label for emotion classification.

I'm trying to train a dataset with 400 samples. For each epoch, from each sample a random trial of shape (C, 1280) is selected with the given label.
Since the used time-points are only 1/10 of the whole sample, I was thinking to create a trainer that, for each epoch, for each sample:

- gets N trials of size (C, 1280), sliding a window of 1280 time-points over the whole sample;
- gets N labels, one for each trial;
- assigns to the sample, the label that got the majority among the N labels.

The solution I'm thinking about is that of:

- create N datasets, each one samples the eeg data, fetching a fixed window;
- Train simoultaneisy a model using the N given datasets (using SequentialSampler, simultaneously batches will be formed based on the same sample);
- calculate the cross-entropy using only the label that gave the majority among the N labels.

I'm not very happy about this solution: is it necessary to create N Datasets?
Does, for example, DataLoader in pytorch could fetch the sample N times, with a sliding window instead?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just manage the samples within the same Dataset? You can add whatever methods you need to the Dataset. I don't think I understand really. Are you trying to train each sample in multiple batches at the same time?

Comment: @igodfried yes, it may be a solution. The main idea is that samples are too long for my  model: the trainer at each epoch can view only a short portion of each sample, thus making the class prediction  seeing only a small (too small) part of the sample. The idea is that of multiple observers that see different portions of the same samples, and then they all decide (with majority vote) what they have seen. The crucial point is that class prediction should be done, after seeing all the time-serie.